# Moblog POP3 problems

Tags: module, email

Im experimenting with Moblog as would really like to get this to publish short read entries into my site. Ive got it working to some extent, its publishing to channel entries and I could display those with templates if I wish. But, every time I check for new emails, I get all the emails again, and they create new (repeat) entries.

Any idea why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Comment: Update: I *think* this is caused by manually checking for emails using the 'check moblog' button in the cp. When I let the system update using the Moblog check time it seems to pick up just the latest email, and nothing is duplicated. My next challenge is getting the formatting to come through properly!

Comment: They should function identically, and in fact execute the same code. Are you getting the message "Unable to delete email" in the control panel after manually checking it?

Comment: Update: I think (maybe as I was testing on localhost) that some errors were initially happening to the POP behaviour and emails weren't being deleted from the email account - so everything kept coming in again. Later it all cleared up and all each email was deleted on being downloaded to EE - as it should be with POP. After that everything behaved normally :)